# googlebot crawling webservice

Tags: ajax, web-services, googlebot

is there some way to make googlebot not to crawl links that is used for webservice? When I try to access my webservice on url it returns 500 error when there no parameters passed.
Or is there also some way to prevent an http 500 error when I try to access my webservice in url without parameters?

THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) to create a robots.txt.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. Also Im calling the the webservice through jquery ajax, just wondering if I put the webservice in robots.txt, will it also prevent the googlebot to crawl the links on the script? sorry Im not good with this seo thing.

Comment: With the robots.txt you can decide which URL's should be crawled. So if you have a page index.php that does ajax calls to webservice.php?param1=123&param2=456 and you put in robots.txt that it should not crawl webservice.php, then it will crawl index.php and not webservice.php.